# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" when using canopy with python

Tags: python, file, io

I am using canopy to learn python (day 1)

Using the below code, I get the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` and no csv file pops up or any get updated (I created a file by the name `index.csv`)

I have tried doing stuff but nothing seems to work. Please help!

**Open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased**

```
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])
```

and I get this:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SPINDEX_CODE.py in <module>()
      21 # open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased
      22 with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
 ---> 23 writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])

 ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: indentation matters

Answer (score 1):

Indentation *does* matter.

```
with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([name, price, datetime.now()])
```

When the `with` block exits, the file is closed automatically. Your `writerow` call is thus made *after* the file is closed, since you have indented it outside the `with...as` block. So, the natural fix is to move move both lines of code to underneath the `with...as` header.

Note that you cannot simply *just* indent the second line (without moving the first line down) because that would lead to inconsistent indent within that block, so don't do it.